# Loading a GET string in a view loader

Tags: php, codeigniter

I keep getting, an unable to load requested file error. Does anybody know how I can add a GET string to the view loader below?

```
if ($userType == 'regular') {

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   $data = array('firstname' => $row->firstname);
   $this->load->view('reg-user/dashboard.php?requestedPageType=wall_1', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo.

You cant pass a query string to a view.
Your view files name must end in .php

Use the data array to pass your additional infos instead.

Comment: Dont pay attention to suckers below. Just remind passing variables via urls isnt a good practice in CI. Use your data array to pass data instead. Wish u luck

Answer (score 0):

GET Strings are the ones following a question mark (query strings)

if you have

```
name=value
name2=value2
```

Just add it on to

```
$this->load->view('reg-user/dashboard.php?requestedPageType=wall_1&name=value&name2=value2');
```

So your statement would be

```
$this->load->view('reg-user/dashboard.php?requestedPageType=wall_1&name=value&firstname='.urlencode($row=>firstname));
```

I'm not sure about your loop but I presume you want each row to be encapsulated into a query string

so try this as your code if this is what you want to do:

```
if ($userType == 'regular') {

$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   array_push($data, $row);
}

$query_string = http_build_query($data);
$this->load->view('reg-user/dashboard.php?requestedPageType=wall_1&'.$query_string);

}
```

Comment: It's `array()`, not `Array()`.